# How to make NameValueCollection serializable?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to make NameValueCollection or a derived class serializable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NameObjectCollectionBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.aspx) ([NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx)'s base class) already implements [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx).